# Is it allowed to draw a matplotlib.patches.Rectangle on a blank figure with matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

This code adds an rectangle on the Lenna image.

```
imgurl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png/330px-Lenna_%28test_image%29.png'
f = urllib.request.urlopen(imgurl)
img = plt.imread(f)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img)
rect = patches.Rectangle((50, 50), 50, 30, linewidth=1, edgecolor='b', facecolor='w')
ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.show()
```

while this code cannot do the job on a blank figure

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
rect = patches.Rectangle((50, 50), 50, 30, linewidth=1, edgecolor='b', facecolor='r')
ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.show()
```

why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your second part of code I get:

[image]

Please notice the x and y axis scale. They each go up to 1.0, but your rectangle patch has coordinates of (50,50). Let's expand the axis limits:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((50,50), 50, 30, linewidth=1, edgecolor='b', facecolor='r')
ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 150)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 150)
plt.show()
```

And you get:

[image]

As you can see, it is plotting the rectangle onto an empty axis, it's just that you couldn't see it the first time around, due to rectangle being out of the view of the axis.